# pound conf file location osx brew

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, pound

Where is the pound configuration file location on os x when installed from brew?

I have been looking at /

find / -name "pound.cfg" * 2>/dev/null

Found nothing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out mysql after all
/usr/local/etc/pound.cfg